# Replace current application with rebuilt version from new Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

### Information:

Currently, I have an application on the market that is actively used.  Rather than refactor all my code to rebuild the application, I rebuilt the whole application from scratch in a new Android Studio Project with identical/updated information (applicationId/packageId/versions).  I want to upload this apk to the google play store to have it update users normally.

### Problem:

Testing this situation on my devices hasn't worked.  I have a device with the 'old' application on it and I attempt to install the 'new' version and I receive this error during installation: "The package seems to be corrupt"

### Question:

Is this process even possible?  If so, why might I be getting this error?  If not, what is the method by which I could do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible as you say, however you need to keep three things in mind:

- Package name must be the same
- Signing key must be the same
- Version number must be higher than last version

Other than that, there should be no problems

Answer (score 2):

You are not going to be able to push the update to the play store with your new project, because the file that you sign the application with (signing key), is associated with your project old SHA 1 and without that file, you cannot push an update.

I suggest you create a new copy of your old project and work there